# Setting Up Windows 7 Perfmon to Collect Performance Data - which data to collect?

Tags: performance, excel, admin, performancecounter, perfmon

How to collect process memory usage (Excel 2010) ?

Which performance data should I choose to show my boss that my computer is too slow for working with large files (~130 Mb) with Excel 2010 64-bit under Windows 7 ?

(I'm working on Intel 3i-2100 3.1 GHz, 4 GB RAM)

one of the problem is that system freeze and do nothing, so processor is 0% etc.

This looks like soft question, but I think it is important.

Comment: I would suggest not worry about trying to collect performance data and actually review some of the websites over the web that talk about Excel performance. A 130mb file (especially in Excel 2010) sounds like a horror story waiting to happen.

Comment: @Nicholosophy and it's happen all the time ...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Excel 2010 PowerPivot add on.  PowerPivot is the SQL Analysis Services engine for Excel, and can do alot with data, all on the local client PC.

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx
- Heres one of many demo's of PowerPivot, to showcase some basic functionality - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/featureVideoBIVideos.aspx?videoId=-gBbnKnILLc

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Excel is simply not made to work with this kind of file. Try injecting this data into a database and work from there. Or try to aggregate the data if you want to stick with excel... for example using hourly aggregations instead of 1 minute raw data.

Comment: I dont understand why people in this question are saying this, when nobody knows what that data is or how the excel file is being used.  Excel 2010 is designed for 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns - thats 17,179,869,184 possible fields per workSHEET.  (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=1)  File size limitations are imposed mainly bc of available space on the client PC.